# Which API security to use for an external API consumed by Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-client-side

Context: Got an API running with a simple /auth call that expects email, password and some sort of db identifier. Which then returns a JWT token. This token can be used to request the other calls and know which database to access. The client is now in UWP which handles the UI and does the calls to the API. Not using Azure Api Management for now and not using the Microsoft Identity platform. Just a regular password hash check.

Recently, we wanted to switch from UWP to a Blazor WASM (client only) but haven't really found any suitable support to work with Bearer tokens and the documentation steers us towards four options.

- AAD
- AAD B2C
- Microsoft Accounts
- Authentication library (?)

Not all our users have Office 365 accounts.

Kind of lost in this new "Blazor space" since it's very different from our WPF & UWP projects and it doesn't seem to be fully documented yet.

Thanks.

---

Update code on request

**Program.cs**

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        // Local storage access
        builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

        builder.Services.AddTransient<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IAccessTokenProvider, ApiTokenProvider>();

        builder.Services
            .AddHttpClient<IMambaClient, MambaClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = _baseUri)
            .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>()
            .ConfigureHandler(new[] { _apiEndpointUrl }));

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

**ApiTokenProvider.cs**

```
public class ApiTokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

    public ApiTokenProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
    {
        _localStorageService = localStorageService;
    }

    public async ValueTask<AccessTokenResult> RequestAccessToken()
    {
        var token = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("Token");

        AccessTokenResult accessTokenResult;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            accessTokenResult = new AccessTokenResult(AccessTokenResultStatus.Success, new AccessToken() { Value = token, Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1))  }, "/");
        }
        else
        {
            accessTokenResult = new AccessTokenResult(AccessTokenResultStatus.RequiresRedirect, new AccessToken() { Value = token, Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)) }, "/login");
        }

        return await new ValueTask<AccessTokenResult>(accessTokenResult);
    }

    public ValueTask<AccessTokenResult> RequestAccessToken(AccessTokenRequestOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**New question**: How will I be able to call POST /auth now if this would work? I would get an error since I don't have a token yet for this TypedClient and adding another typed client isn't possible since I cannot give it a different name?

Comment: You should find what you need [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: You can implements your [IAccessTokenProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.iaccesstokenprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  to get the token from your api.

Comment: @aguafrommars again the documentation is not clear at all. I tried to do it. I added my typed client as a IHttpClientFactory but then what? There's nothing to find on how to implement IAccessTokenProvider or what it all does. Can't find any working example either. Same for "AuthorizationMessageHandler" , can't find nothing on it. Visual Studio just gives an error it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's an interface, you just have to implement 2 methods, register your custom class in DI. That's it.

Comment: @aguafrommars Okay makes sense. So in the implementation of those methods I just query the localstorage for the token and that's it? And where does this implementation gets called?

Comment: @aguafrommars I got it running but the implementation of the IAccessTokenProvider doesn't get called at all. Breakpoints don't hit at all.

Comment: Post your program.cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214857/discussion-between-jesse-and-agua-from-mars).

Comment: Ok, but you didn't get token as you did with your UWP app by calling the method returning the token on your API, right ?

Comment: @aguafrommars in the login page I added inject IMambaClient MambaClient and then I just call: await MambaClient.ApiUserAuthenticateAsync(authRequest);
The call executes fine, I get a token but the next call is an Authorized call which then fails because it didn't receive the token.
I tried adding a custom implementation of AuthorizationMessageHandler which seem to work somehow (Calling ApiTokenProvider in there) but not sure of the implementation and what should be in there. I added the Authorization header if the token is available. But then can't use the login anymore, see my post.

Comment: Don't use your IMamba client on your login page, inject an HttpClient not comming from the IHttpClientFactory, and inject the ILocalStorageService to store the token

Comment: @aguafrommars Fair enough, I could do that. One more question though: is it normal to have a custom AuthorizationMessageHandler as well? Since I can't see any example of it anywhere but I did a custom implementation of it and if I do that, my breakpoints hit and I can modify the header and then it makes sense to me.

Comment: @aguafrommars for now I added a check in the CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler to check if I was on the login page or not and skip the whole step and redirect if I am. But separate HttpClient is probably better.

Also I'm not using the " catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)" anywhere since my custom implementation takes care of this. Not sure if it's the right way?
 Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You should avoid catching exception if possible